# Why does the official helm chart for fluent-bit start 20 pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, fluent-bit

I followed the official helm chart for fluent-bit and ended up with 20 pods, in a namespace. How do I configure it to use 1 pod?

The replicaCount attribute in values.yaml is set to 1.

https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/fluent-bit

```
helm upgrade -i fluent-bit helm/efk/fluent-bit --namespace some-ns

kubectl get pods -n some-ns


NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fluent-bit-22dx4        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-2x6rn        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-42rfd        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-54drx        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-8f8pl        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-8rtp9        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-8wfcc        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-bffh8        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-lgl9k        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-lqdrs        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-mdvlc        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-qgvww        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-qqwh6        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-qxbjt        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-rqr8g        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-t8vbv        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-vkcfl        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-wnwtq        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-xqwxk        1/1     Running   0          15h
fluent-bit-xxj8q        1/1     Running   0          15h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are two deployment kinds in your template, **daemonset** and **deployment**.

This is controlled by the **kind** field of the values file.

Now **daemonset** is written in the values, so it will be on each node without considering the affinity Start a replica.

If you want to start one, please set kind to **Deployment**, then set replicaCount to 1 and redeploy.

values.yaml

```
# Default values for fluent-bit.

# kind -- DaemonSet or Deployment
kind: Deployment

# replicaCount -- Only applicable if kind=Deployment
replicaCount: 1
```

> > https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/
> > https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/